# Dynamics 365 - Data Migration - Export Portal Entities

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm facing a very weard bug trying to export records from my Dyn365 Portal environment.

Anyone is getting the same error?

Error message:
RetrieveMultiple: GetEntityDataSearchParams |=> Failed to download a file entity [Annotation] with Id...
The specified blob does not exist...

Thank you all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue.
Corrupt Note records was the culprit.
After remove all the records and create it again, i'm good to go...